# Passing C++ variable in MySQL Statement using MySQL Driver in MySQL 8.0+

Tags: mysql, c++11, variables

I have looked through Stack Overflow's plethora of answers and questions but they are all for older versions of MySQL. I have also scoured the bowls of the internet for an answer to this and tried numerous different methods to no avail. So the question, how do I use a C++ variable in a MySQL query.

For instance:

 
`pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = [C++ Var]");`

Where [C++ Var] would be the C++ variable. I am not sure if it is a good idea to use older methods from MySQL 5 in MySQL 8 or not. I think the most effective way would be to use the `SET @var_name = data` method, but I cannot find any way to implement that in C++. Currently I am using MySQL/C++ Connector 8.0 with the driver. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need to use a MySQL `@xxx` variable here.

Using the old MySQL C++ API (which seems to be modeled after the Java JDBC API) `prepareStatment` call should look like:

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE id = ?");
```

And later on you should use something like

```
pstmt->setInt(1, userId); //where userId is a C++ int
ResultSet res* = pstmt->executeQuery()
```

Using the newer C++ API ([X Dev API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/method-chaining.html)) the calls would look similar to the following:

```
Table accounts = db.getTable("accounts");
auto query = accounts.select("balance").where("id = :account_id");

RowResult res = query.bind("account_id", account_id).execute(); // where account_id is the name of an int variable.
```

Comment: That's a lot more info than I could find anywhere else. I will try to get that to work when I get back home tonight.

Comment: Thank you @nimrodm for this answer it works! I wish there was more documentation for c++ or even other languages that may not have such.

Comment: Glad it helped, @mcdz89. What API did you end up using? The old JDBC or the new X-Dev?

Comment: I used the old JDBC API as it is what I am currently working with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

These chaining examples all appear to be based on a query involving a single table. But real queries frequently involve relations between several tables.
And this works just as well. Note that if there are several variables you bind them in the order they appear.

```
// Perform any operations on the table or query data as needed
string sql = "Select distinct foodname, price, storename from prices \
        join foods on(foods.foodkey = prices.foodkey) \
        join stores on(stores.storekey = prices.storekey) \
        where price > ? and storename like ?";
           
    //bind two parameters to the query
    SqlStatement query = session.sql(sql);
    float pval = 2.0;
    query.bind(pval);
    query.bind("V%");
    
    SqlResult res = query.execute();
```

And you can rebind new parameters and run the query again without it being recompiled.